# created a sublist (list3) from an instance of LinkedList (list1) , invoked clear() method on sublist, did not expect list1 to be changed as well

Tags: java, list

After creating a sublist (i.e. `list3`) from `list1`, I invoked clear() method on `list3`, expecting that list3 will be cleared while list1 will be left untouched. However, the result clearly indicate that list1 has been changed as well. Why is this happening?

```
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(null, 22, 33, 44, 22));

List<Integer> list3 = list1.subList(1, 3);
System.out.println(list3);

list3.clear();

System.out.println(list3);
System.out.println(list1);
```

result:

```
[22, 33]
[]
[null, 44, 22]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you want, you would need to make a copy of the sublist.

Just calling subList "Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.", "The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa."

[[java.util.List API documentation]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)